# React out of memory

Tags: reactjs, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

In the course of my work, a rather rare bug appears randomly when a link is clicked on a page.
To try and reproduce the bug, I've coded a small script that performs the actions automatically (clicks on buttons to go from one page to another).
Schematically :

```
(async () => {
    const sleep = delay => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay * 1000));

    for (let i = 0; ; i++) {
        console.log(`#${i}`);
        
        while (true) {
            btn = document.querySelector(".btn-next");
            if (btn) break;
            await sleep(1);
        }
        btn.click();

        await sleep(1);

        while (true) {
            btn = document.querySelector(".btn-prev");
            if (btn) break;
            await sleep(1);
        }
        btn.click();
        
        await sleep(1);
    }
})();
```

After a certain number of iterations (around 200), the script crashes: `out of memory`.
I don't understand why this happens, because in my opinion, there is no memory leak in the above code.
I deduce that the memory leak is somewhere else (for example, when leaving a page, you forget to release certain resources).
The application is coded in React.
I'd like the community's opinion on whether the memory leak could be in the above code.
Thanks in advance!